# Why is there a big difference in latch waits for an update against a table variable vs temp table?

Tags: sql-server

Help me to understand latches difference between table variable and temp table.
Example:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @t TABLE (id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ss varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t (ss)
    VALUES ('TestTest'), ('TestTest')

declare @n int = 0

WHILE  @n < 100000
BEGIN
    SET @n += 1

    UPDATE @t
    SET ss = REVERSE(ss)
END
```

Run it!
And check wait statistic:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats WHERE session_id = <spid>
```

Result:

```
session_id wait_type                                                    waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms         max_wait_time_ms     signal_wait_time_ms

951        PAGELATCH_SH                                                 1                    0                    0                    0
951        PAGELATCH_EX                                                 200002               12655                379                  12414
951        SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD                                          22                   636                  205                  636
951        MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT                                        45                   0                    0                    0
```

It seems that latches were taken 2 times for insert and 200000 times for update.
But when we switch table variable (@t) to temp table (#t) we have no latches at all:

```
session_id wait_type                                                    waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms         max_wait_time_ms     signal_wait_time_ms

1108       SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD                                          910                  83                   4                    82
1108       MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT                                        110                  0                    0                    0
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why we have latches in table variable and no one for temp table?
2. Why latches taken for EVERY row? Why not only once per update (transaction)?

Comment: read the answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Lamak - I don't cover this in that answer unfortunately - this difference is a new one for me. I imagine that the explanation is the same as in "Lazy Latches" here https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-plan/optimizing-update-queries the call stack for the table variable update has a lot of latch activity not present for the temp table https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6WJ.png

Comment: Martin Smith - Thanks. It seems like the answer for me. But I'm not sure. So I don't know what to do next with my question )) I'm confused to realize that table variable could be so slow.

Comment: https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/06/23/introduction-to-latches-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that latches were taken ... 200000 times
>   for update

Your query is showing the number of latch waits - not the number of latches taken but this is still an interesting difference. Below is a partial answer. It explains what is going on but not why the discrepancy exists.

It is based on the information supplied in Paul White's blog post [Optimizing Update Queries](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-plan/optimizing-update-queries)

For the update with a table variable in this case the plan has a clustered index scan on the RHS

[image]

The clustered index scan takes a shared latch on the page and does not release it when outputting the row values. The output columns of the clustered index scan are `id` and `ss` - the string is reversed then the clustered index update operator looks up the row for the passed in `id` (`sqlmin.dll!CValFetchByKeyForUpdate::ManipData` below) and updates the row. It needs an exclusive latch to update the page but is blocked by the shared latch held by the scan. So it needs to go into a wait state for the latch which then releases the shared latch and unblocks itself as described in the Lazy Latches section of the linked blog post.

(**table variable hot path**)

[image]

When using a temporary table it is able to use rowset sharing. This is also described in the linked post

> ... special optimization that means the Clustered Index Scan and
>   Clustered Index Update share the same rowset ... the Update no longer has to locate the row to update – it is already positioned correctly by the read.

The code path for that is very different than for the table variable as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAbu5.png).

This seems to avoid the problem with the lazy latching described above. It still takes an SH latch at the beginning but then releases it before trying to acquire the EX latch and maintains the EX latch for the rest of the Update. So at no point does it have to wait

**latching on page for #temp table update (of two rows)**

[image]

**latching on page for @table variable update (of two rows)**

[image]

The additional information added to execution plans by trace flag 8666 shows that the two plans have differing values for `m_isolationLevelHint` and `m_lockModeHint` in the update operator.

Maybe these need to be a certain value to get the rowset sharing optimisation(?)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm impressed by your answer. I have the last question: how do you get those stacks? Could you give some link to teach how to do that?

Comment: The stacks are from using windows performance recorder for the few seconds that the loop was running and opening the resulting report in Windows performance analyser. These are both free tools you can download from the Microsoft website.